# C# Use XPath to query a XSD File

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a XSD that define a complex screen data.
XSD contains some elements like:

I made a mistake in the first post, I removed ns (xs:)

```
<xs:element name="COUNTRY2" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <CAPTION>Pays</CAPTION>
            <SHORTCAPTION>Pays</SHORTCAPTION>
            <FLAGS>0</FLAGS>
            <VISIBLE>1</VISIBLE>
            <LISTWIDTH>100</LISTWIDTH>
            <FLDTYPE>8</FLDTYPE>
            <LOOKUP>
                <Item C="" D="" />
                <Item C="AF" D="AFGHANISTAN" />
                <Item C="ZA" D="AFRIQUE DU SUD" />
                <Item C="AX" D="ÅLAND - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="AL" D="ALBANIE" />
                <Item C="DZ" D="ALGÉRIE" />
                <Item C="DE" D="ALLEMAGNE" />
                <Item C="AD" D="ANDORRE" />
                <Item C="AO" D="ANGOLA" />
                <Item C="AI" D="ANGUILLA" />
                <Item C="AQ" D="ANTARCTIQUE" />
                <Item C="AG" D="ANTIGUA-ET-BARBUDA" />
                <Item C="AN" D="ANTILLES NÉERLANDAISES" />
                <Item C="SA" D="ARABIE SAOUDITE" />
                <Item C="AR" D="ARGENTINE" />
                <Item C="AM" D="ARMÉNIE" />
                <Item C="AW" D="ARUBA" />
                <Item C="AU" D="AUSTRALIE" />
                <Item C="AT" D="AUTRICHE" />
                <Item C="AZ" D="AZERBAÏDJAN" />
                <Item C="BS" D="BAHAMAS" />
                <Item C="BH" D="BAHREÏN" />
                <Item C="BD" D="BANGLADESH" />
                <Item C="BB" D="BARBADE" />
                <Item C="BY" D="BÉLARUS" />
                <Item C="BE" D="BELGIQUE" />
                <Item C="BZ" D="BELIZE" />
                <Item C="BJ" D="BÉNIN" />
                <Item C="BM" D="BERMUDES" />
                <Item C="BT" D="BHOUTAN" />
                <Item C="BO" D="BOLIVIE" />
                <Item C="BA" D="BOSNIE-HERZÉGOVINE" />
                <Item C="BW" D="BOTSWANA" />
                <Item C="BV" D="BOUVET - ÎLE" />
                <Item C="BR" D="BRÉSIL" />
                <Item C="BN" D="BRUNÉI DARUSSALAM" />
                <Item C="BG" D="BULGARIE" />
                <Item C="BF" D="BURKINA FASO" />
                <Item C="BI" D="BURUNDI" />
                <Item C="KY" D="CAÏMANES - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="KH" D="CAMBODGE" />
                <Item C="CM" D="CAMEROUN" />
                <Item C="CA" D="CANADA" />
                <Item C="CV" D="CAP-VERT" />
                <Item C="CF" D="CENTRAFRICAINE - RÉPUBLIQUE" />
                <Item C="CL" D="CHILI" />
                <Item C="CN" D="CHINE" />
                <Item C="CX" D="CHRISTMAS - ÎLE" />
                <Item C="CY" D="CHYPRE" />
                <Item C="CC" D="COCOS (KEELING) - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="CO" D="COLOMBIE" />
                <Item C="KM" D="COMORES" />
                <Item C="CG" D="CONGO" />
                <Item C="CD" D="CONGO - LA RÉPUBLIQUE DÉMOCRATIQUE DU" />
                <Item C="CK" D="COOK - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="KR" D="CORÉE - RÉPUBLIQUE DE" />
                <Item C="KP" D="CORÉE - RÉPUBLIQUE POPULAIRE DÉMOCRATIQUE DE" />
                <Item C="CR" D="COSTA RICA" />
                <Item C="CI" D="CÔTE D'IVOIRE" />
                <Item C="HR" D="CROATIE" />
                <Item C="CU" D="CUBA" />
                <Item C="DK" D="DANEMARK" />
                <Item C="DJ" D="DJIBOUTI" />
                <Item C="DO" D="DOMINICAINE  RÉPUBLIQUE" />
                <Item C="DM" D="DOMINIQUE" />
                <Item C="EG" D="ÉGYPTE" />
                <Item C="SV" D="EL SALVADOR" />
                <Item C="AE" D="ÉMIRATS ARABES UNIS" />
                <Item C="EC" D="ÉQUATEUR" />
                <Item C="ER" D="ÉRYTHRÉE" />
                <Item C="ES" D="ESPAGNE" />
                <Item C="EE" D="ESTONIE" />
                <Item C="US" D="ÉTATS-UNIS" />
                <Item C="ET" D="ÉTHIOPIE" />
                <Item C="FK" D="FALKLAND - ÎLES (MALVINAS)" />
                <Item C="FO" D="FÉROÉ - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="FJ" D="FIDJI" />
                <Item C="FI" D="FINLANDE" />
                <Item C="FR" D="FRANCE" />
                <Item C="GA" D="GABON" />
                <Item C="GM" D="GAMBIE" />
                <Item C="GE" D="GÉORGIE" />
                <Item C="GS" D="GÉORGIE DU SUD ET LES ÎLES SANDWICH DU SUD" />
                <Item C="GH" D="GHANA" />
                <Item C="GI" D="GIBRALTAR" />
                <Item C="GR" D="GRÈCE" />
                <Item C="GD" D="GRENADE" />
                <Item C="GL" D="GROENLAND" />
                <Item C="GP" D="GUADELOUPE" />
                <Item C="GU" D="GUAM" />
                <Item C="GT" D="GUATEMALA" />
                <Item C="GG" D="GUERNESEY" />
                <Item C="GN" D="GUINÉE" />
                <Item C="GW" D="GUINÉE-BISSAU" />
                <Item C="GQ" D="GUINÉE ÉQUATORIALE" />
                <Item C="GY" D="GUYANA" />
                <Item C="GF" D="GUYANE FRANÇAISE" />
                <Item C="HT" D="HAÏTI" />
                <Item C="HM" D="HEARD - ÎLE ET MCDONALD - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="HN" D="HONDURAS" />
                <Item C="HK" D="HONG-KONG" />
                <Item C="HU" D="HONGRIE" />
                <Item C="IM" D="ÎLE DE MAN" />
                <Item C="UM" D="ÎLES MINEURES ÉLOIGNÉES DES ÉTATS-UNIS" />
                <Item C="VG" D="ÎLES VIERGES BRITANNIQUES" />
                <Item C="VI" D="ÎLES VIERGES DES ÉTATS-UNIS" />
                <Item C="IN" D="INDE" />
                <Item C="ID" D="INDONÉSIE" />
                <Item C="IR" D="IRAN - RÉPUBLIQUE ISLAMIQUE D'" />
                <Item C="IQ" D="IRAQ" />
                <Item C="IE" D="IRLANDE" />
                <Item C="IS" D="ISLANDE" />
                <Item C="IL" D="ISRAËL" />
                <Item C="IT" D="ITALIE" />
                <Item C="JM" D="JAMAÏQUE" />
                <Item C="JP" D="JAPON" />
                <Item C="JE" D="JERSEY" />
                <Item C="JO" D="JORDANIE" />
                <Item C="KZ" D="KAZAKHSTAN" />
                <Item C="KE" D="KENYA" />
                <Item C="KG" D="KIRGHIZISTAN" />
                <Item C="KI" D="KIRIBATI" />
                <Item C="KW" D="KOWEÏT" />
                <Item C="LA" D="LAO - RÉPUBLIQUE DÉMOCRATIQUE POPULAIRE" />
                <Item C="LS" D="LESOTHO" />
                <Item C="LV" D="LETTONIE" />
                <Item C="LB" D="LIBAN" />
                <Item C="LR" D="LIBÉRIA" />
                <Item C="LY" D="LIBYENNE - JAMAHIRIYA ARABE" />
                <Item C="LI" D="LIECHTENSTEIN" />
                <Item C="LT" D="LITUANIE" />
                <Item C="LU" D="LUXEMBOURG" />
                <Item C="MO" D="MACAO" />
                <Item C="MK" D="MACÉDOINE - EX-RÉPUBLIQUE YOUGOSLAVE DE" />
                <Item C="MG" D="MADAGASCAR" />
                <Item C="MY" D="MALAISIE" />
                <Item C="MW" D="MALAWI" />
                <Item C="MV" D="MALDIVES" />
                <Item C="ML" D="MALI" />
                <Item C="MT" D="MALTE" />
                <Item C="MP" D="MARIANNES DU NORD - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="MA" D="MAROC" />
                <Item C="MH" D="MARSHALL - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="MQ" D="MARTINIQUE" />
                <Item C="MU" D="MAURICE" />
                <Item C="MR" D="MAURITANIE" />
                <Item C="YT" D="MAYOTTE" />
                <Item C="MX" D="MEXIQUE" />
                <Item C="FM" D="MICRONÉSIE - ÉTATS FÉDÉRÉS DE" />
                <Item C="MD" D="MOLDOVA - RÉPUBLIQUE DE" />
                <Item C="MC" D="MONACO" />
                <Item C="MN" D="MONGOLIE" />
                <Item C="ME" D="MONTÉNÉGRO" />
                <Item C="MS" D="MONTSERRAT" />
                <Item C="MZ" D="MOZAMBIQUE" />
                <Item C="MM" D="MYANMAR" />
                <Item C="NA" D="NAMIBIE" />
                <Item C="NR" D="NAURU" />
                <Item C="NP" D="NÉPAL" />
                <Item C="NI" D="NICARAGUA" />
                <Item C="NE" D="NIGER" />
                <Item C="NG" D="NIGÉRIA" />
                <Item C="NU" D="NIUÉ" />
                <Item C="NF" D="NORFOLK - ÎLE" />
                <Item C="NO" D="NORVÈGE" />
                <Item C="NC" D="NOUVELLE-CALÉDONIE" />
                <Item C="NZ" D="NOUVELLE-ZÉLANDE" />
                <Item C="IO" D="OCÉAN INDIEN - TERRITOIRE BRITANNIQUE DE L'" />
                <Item C="OM" D="OMAN" />
                <Item C="UG" D="OUGANDA" />
                <Item C="UZ" D="OUZBÉKISTAN" />
                <Item C="PK" D="PAKISTAN" />
                <Item C="PW" D="PALAOS" />
                <Item C="PS" D="PALESTINIEN OCCUPÉ - TERRITOIRE" />
                <Item C="PA" D="PANAMA" />
                <Item C="PG" D="PAPOUASIE-NOUVELLE-GUINÉE" />
                <Item C="PY" D="PARAGUAY" />
                <Item C="NL" D="PAYS-BAS" />
                <Item C="PE" D="PÉROU" />
                <Item C="PH" D="PHILIPPINES" />
                <Item C="PN" D="PITCAIRN" />
                <Item C="PL" D="POLOGNE" />
                <Item C="PF" D="POLYNÉSIE FRANÇAISE" />
                <Item C="PR" D="PORTO RICO" />
                <Item C="PT" D="PORTUGAL" />
                <Item C="QA" D="QATAR" />
                <Item C="RE" D="RÉUNION" />
                <Item C="RO" D="ROUMANIE" />
                <Item C="GB" D="ROYAUME-UNI" />
                <Item C="RU" D="RUSSIE - FÉDÉRATION DE" />
                <Item C="RW" D="RWANDA" />
                <Item C="EH" D="SAHARA OCCIDENTAL" />
                <Item C="SH" D="SAINTE-HÉLÈNE" />
                <Item C="LC" D="SAINTE-LUCIE" />
                <Item C="KN" D="SAINT-KITTS-ET-NEVIS" />
                <Item C="SM" D="SAINT-MARIN" />
                <Item C="PM" D="SAINT-PIERRE-ET-MIQUELON" />
                <Item C="VA" D="SAINT-SIÈGE (ÉTAT DE LA CITÉ DU VATICAN)" />
                <Item C="VC" D="SAINT-VINCENT-ET-LES GRENADINES" />
                <Item C="SB" D="SALOMON - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="WS" D="SAMOA" />
                <Item C="AS" D="SAMOA AMÉRICAINES" />
                <Item C="ST" D="SAO TOMÉ-ET-PRINCIPE" />
                <Item C="SN" D="SÉNÉGAL" />
                <Item C="RS" D="SERBIE" />
                <Item C="SC" D="SEYCHELLES" />
                <Item C="SL" D="SIERRA LEONE" />
                <Item C="SG" D="SINGAPOUR" />
                <Item C="SK" D="SLOVAQUIE" />
                <Item C="SI" D="SLOVÉNIE" />
                <Item C="SO" D="SOMALIE" />
                <Item C="SD" D="SOUDAN" />
                <Item C="LK" D="SRI LANKA" />
                <Item C="SE" D="SUÈDE" />
                <Item C="CH" D="SUISSE" />
                <Item C="SR" D="SURINAME" />
                <Item C="SJ" D="SVALBARD ET ÎLE JAN MAYEN" />
                <Item C="SZ" D="SWAZILAND" />
                <Item C="SY" D="SYRIENNE - RÉPUBLIQUE ARABE" />
                <Item C="TJ" D="TADJIKISTAN" />
                <Item C="TW" D="TAÏWAN - PROVINCE DE CHINE" />
                <Item C="TZ" D="TANZANIE - RÉPUBLIQUE-UNIE DE" />
                <Item C="TD" D="TCHAD" />
                <Item C="CZ" D="TCHÈQUE - RÉPUBLIQUE" />
                <Item C="TF" D="TERRES AUSTRALES FRANÇAISES" />
                <Item C="TH" D="THAÏLANDE" />
                <Item C="TL" D="TIMOR-LESTE" />
                <Item C="TG" D="TOGO" />
                <Item C="TK" D="TOKELAU" />
                <Item C="TO" D="TONGA" />
                <Item C="TT" D="TRINITÉ-ET-TOBAGO" />
                <Item C="TN" D="TUNISIE" />
                <Item C="TM" D="TURKMÉNISTAN" />
                <Item C="TC" D="TURKS ET CAÏQUES - ÎLES" />
                <Item C="TR" D="TURQUIE" />
                <Item C="TV" D="TUVALU" />
                <Item C="UA" D="UKRAINE" />
                <Item C="UY" D="URUGUAY" />
                <Item C="VU" D="VANUATU" />
                <Item C="VE" D="VENEZUELA" />
                <Item C="VN" D="VIET NAM" />
                <Item C="WF" D="WALLIS ET FUTUNA" />
                <Item C="YE" D="YÉMEN" />
                <Item C="ZM" D="ZAMBIE" />
                <Item C="ZW" D="ZIMBABWE" />
            </LOOKUP>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

To feed the Countries I have this XPath :

```
//xs:element[@name='COUNTRY2']//LOOKUP/Item
```

I don't find a solution for this to works.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to feed ComboBox with options build with data obtained with this xpath.

Comment: I trasfered the treatment serverside and it works with a namespace manager. I read IE does not support XPath anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `//Item` -- that should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @YuriPrezument Sure it does ;)